# How do I charge my Apple device at its normal rate?

Tags: apt, power-management, ppa, asus, apple

I use an iPad 9.7" and it doesn't charge when connected to USB of my recently purchased Ubuntu 19.10 PC, an Asus [Vivobook X509UA](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-15-X509FL/HelpDesk/). I've gone through some questions here and they are mostly quite old. The latest one suggested to install `ipad-charge` that can be found [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/webupd8-amd64/ipad-charge_1.1+git20161017-1~webupd8~xenial1_amd64.deb.html) but is itself 4 years old and I suspect it's no longer being supported for newer version of Ubuntu.

I've tried the steps provided in the link:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ipad-charge
```

But I get these errors:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/ipad-charge/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any other alternative to charge my iPad at normal rate?

Edit: My machine has 4 USB ports, two are USB 2.0 ports, one is a small USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C port while the last is a USB 3.1 Gen 1 port. Tried charging on standard USB 2.0 ports but doesn't charge at normal rate. The one which is a USB 3.1 port also does not fully charge the device.

Comment: The issue is with heathbar's PPA not nilarimogard/webupd8. The earlier was last updated for 14.04.

Comment: @K7AAY Added required edits

Comment: ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 doesn't have support for 19.10 .. you can always try to follow the url mentioned in the error text (http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/ipad-charge/ubuntu) to see what dists that are supported.

Comment: @Shiv_90 1) Don't use Apple; what do you mean by 'normal rate'? 2) Is https://ipadpilotnews.com/2019/11/charging-your-ipad-what-you-need-to-know-3/ correct? 3) Did the USB-C cnxn charge at normal rate? I noticed you didn't say it didn't....  I asked about yellow USB ports since those are generally high-current ports. Black's normally 1.x, white's normally 2.x, blue's normally 3.0, red's normally 3.1, although there's no official color standard;  watch a manufacturer prove me wrong. 4) What's the make & model of your Ubuntu 19.10 PC? Please get model# from the serial# sticker.

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the inputs. I use a Asus Vivobook X509UA machine that I recently purchased. Ubuntu is 19.10 with GNOME 3.34.1. As for the USB ports, none of them would charge the iPad as they are supposed to do. Even connecting on USB 3.x shows "Not charging" on the device. Earlier I had a 2012 Macbook with USB 2.0 ports and these used to charge any iOS device. Still left to check on Windows though, which occupies the second half of the HDD.

Comment: @Shiv_90 Please do test w/ Windows and check back. If it's a HW issue with the Asus, folks should know.

Comment: @K7AAY Windows test confirmed. iPad won't charge (tested through all USB ports). You think then this is some form of incompatibility of Apple devices? It used to charge well on my earlier MBP.

Comment: Likely. Suggest you write this up as an Answer then click the check mark after finished so other folks can see it.